# converting 3 variable into a matrix form to create a heatmap in SAS

Tags: matrix, sas, heatmap, sas-iml

I'm trying to convert 3 vairables into a matrix, for expample if you have the following:

(CHAR) (char)  (num)

Var1   Var2   Var3

A       B       1

C       D      2

E       F      3

A       D      4

A       F      5

C       B      6

C       F      7

E       B      8

E       D      9

Any ideas on how to convert the above three variables into this form of matrix below and my goal is to construct a heatmap using this matix

```
B   D   F
```

A   1   4   5

C   6   2   7

E   8   9   3

Can anyone help me do this in SAS, either using SAS/IML or other Procedure? Thanks!

Comment: I'd look at the articles on the Do Loop, such as in [this search](http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/tag/heat-maps/), for information about heat maps in IML.  Rick has all sorts of good options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be better if you post your code first then ask questions.

I think `proc transpose` is the fastest solution.

```
data _t1;
input var1 $ var2 $ var3 5.;
cards;
A B 1 
C D 2
E F 3
A D 4
A F 5
C B 6
C F 7
E B 8
E D 9
run;

proc sort data=_t1;by var1;run;

proc transpose data=_t1 out=_t2(drop=_name_ rename=(var1=HereUpToYou));
by var1;
var var3;
id var2;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a recent version of SAS/IML (13.1 or later), use the HEATMAPCONT or HEATMAPDISC call:

```
proc iml;
m = {1 4 5,
     6 2 7,
     8 9 3};
call heatmapcont(m) xvalues={B D F} yvalues={A C E};
```

For details, see [Creating heat maps in SAS/IML](http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2014/08/20/heat-map-in-sasiml/)